# class fires twice

Tags: jquery

Hello:  I'm wondering if it is possible to get the following images to drop down one at a time .  Currently they are both dropping at once when the first one is clicked.  I've tried using removeClass but that has not had any result.

The code appears twice because there are two images I am trying to show.  Both would initially be thumbnails and then if the person was interested they would click and a larger image would appear.  Once done viewing they could click and remove the image and then look at image 2 and have the same opportunity.  If they want to see something larger than the thumbnail they would click on it.  The problem is when the first (or second) thumbnail is clicked both larger images expand at once and then both contract back down again.  I hope this is clear, I can attempt to clarify further if needed.  Thanks

```
<div class="JQuery"><!--Begin JQuery-->
<div class="clickMeA"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="124" height="90" /></div>
<div class="picframeA"><img src="images/1LG.jpg"><p>Here is the text</p></div>
  <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document) .ready(function(){                  
            $(".clickMeA"). click(function() {                                            
            $("img") .fadeIn(1000);
            $(".picframeA") .slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
<div class="clickMeA"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="124" height="90" /></div>
<div class="picframeA"><img src="images/2LG.jpg"><p>Here is the text</p></div>
  <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document) .ready(function(){                  
            $(".clickMeA"). click(function() {
            $("img") .fadeIn(1000);
            $(".picframeA") .slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears you are missing some supporting code snippets.

Comment: Agree with @RobLowe. You need to show your relevant HTML code and describe your problem clearly. Also, unclear about your double posting of js code, clarify why you did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".clickMeA")
```

This gets *all* elements with the class `clickMeA`.

```
$("img")
```

This gets *all* `<img>` tags on the page.

You only need to include your script, and jQuery *once*.  You should put your scripts in your `<head>`, you need to copy&paste the entire script after each div.

The script doesn't until the DOM is ready, so you just need it once, and it will affect all the matched elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // runs after the DOM is ready
    $(".clickMeA").click(function(){ // gets all elements with that class
        // why are you fading in before sliding the div?
        $(this).next(".picframeA").find("img").fadeIn(1000); // target the correct image
        $(this).next(".picframeA").slideToggle("slow"); // target the correct div
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yngEQ/1/

Comment: Thanks for this, I can see I was missing a lot in order for this to work.  Do you have any suggestions for reading/review that would fill in the concepts I am/was missing.  I've come across the use of 'this' but did not understand the concept

Comment: @officemanager2: I can't really suggest anything, sorry.  Just Google around I guess.

Comment: good enough.  If you have time, I'm trying to replicate what you have done on the above link, but for some reason I can not get a new page to work.  If I copy and paste everything from your link above, and include a link to jquery-1.7.2.min.js is there anything missing that would prevent the expansion to the larger images?

Comment: @officemanager2: Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: This error as come up  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Dropped a line on the paste.  Thanks again for your help